# NancyFx: set default charset to utf8

Tags: c#, nancy

I have this snippet in my cshtml file:

```
Expires on: @Model.EndDate.ToString("MMM dd yyyy")
```

And I get this in the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

...
Expires on: ׳�׳�׳™ 05 2013
```

How do I tell Nancy to use UTF8 by default for responses?

---

**Edit:** To clarify, this isn't a localization problem, the output is already localized - it's just that the localized UTF8 string is sent to the client without a UTF8 charset declaration, so it gets mucked up in an attempt to treat it as latin1.

What I am looking for is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

...
```

And I'd like to not have to specify it for each response individually.

I am using the **[NancyFx](http://nancyfx.org/)** web framework

Comment: What's the desired output? For example is it `2013 05 April`? Or do you want a localized month name?

Comment: The date is localized, but the localized string is lost in encoding. So the answer is I guess 'I want a localized month name'.

Comment: Have you tried specifying culture? For example: @Model.EndDate.ToString("ddd d MMM", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-SA"))

Comment: The culture is not the question - the question is "How do I tell [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) to use UTF8 **by default** for responses?".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to specify UTF8 charset declaration in your module's response, you can define an [After interceptor](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-before-and-after-module-hooks). Here's how you can define an After Interceptor in your module's constructor:

```
After += ctx =>
{
    ...
}
```

You can also define Application-level hook in your bootstrapper:

```
pipelines.AfterRequest += (ctx) => { ... };
```

*Update*:
  Based on the comments, best approach would be using the following code in the hook:

```
if (ctx.Response.ContentType == "text/html")
    ctx.Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
```

Comment: I expected Nancy to have something more dedicated built-in, but this solves the problem. :-)

Comment: Actually this isn't working... the value set on `Response` in any after interceptor is ignored. If you put the above code on `NegotiationContext`, then it works, but it screws up json requests because it is called before the Json view renderer had a chance to set the content type. In other words the first part of the if will never be called.

So the search for the correct answer continues I'm afraid... :-\

Comment: OK the correct approach is to use `Response.ContentType`. Since it appears only the HtmlResponse doesn't handle the charset, it's safe to limit it to : `if (ctx.Response.ContentType == "text/html") ctx.Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf8";`. If you edit your answer I'll accept it :-)

Comment: Is there a way to do this globally, rather on a per-module basis?  (After interceptors are per-module)

Comment: @FrankSchwieterman can't you use the application-level hook instead?

Comment: Yes, thank you now I see I can override ApplicationStartup or RequestStartup in the bootstrapper.  My bad.